# error find 'struts.multipart.saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir

Tags: java, mysql, struts2

While trying to upload the Image in mysql db the image is not uploading and showing following msg Unable to find 'struts.multipart.saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir

How to solve this problem

Comment: This message is probably just a warning/debug. Your error is elsewhere. Show some code and configuration.

Comment: struts.xml  
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
 <action class="com.javatpoint.Product" name="imageload" method="imageLoad">
          
            <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg</param>
           
            <result name="success">upload.jsp</result>
            
            <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
</struts>

Comment: Seems you are running devmode, try to turn it off it would suppress some warning or error that might frustrating you.